# Counting number of nodes and leaf nodes in Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Having a little trouble with counting the size of my Binary Tree, and the number of leaves in my binary tree. Should be a simple problem but I having trouble figuring it out nonetheless.

So I'm getting an error: " **error: no matching function for call to âBinaryNode::BinaryNode(BinaryNode*&)â** ". This is occuring on lines 218, 219, 230, 232 (of my .cpp file). All with a note from my header file:  **bet.h:6: note: candidates are: BinaryNode::BinaryNode() BinaryNode::BinaryNode(const BinaryNode&)**. which is on line 6 of my header file. So here's the code. First the start of my header file (that holds my interfaces):

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct BinaryNode
{                      //This is line 6
    string element;
    BinaryNode* leftNode;
    BinaryNode* rightNode;
};

class BET
{
public:
    BET();
    BET(const string postfix);
    BET(const BET&);
    ~BET();
    bool buildFromPostfix(const string postfix);
    const BET& operator= (const BET&);
    void printInfixExpression();
    void printPostfixExpression();
    size_t size();
    size_t leaf_nodes();
    bool empty();

private:
    void printInfixExpression(BinaryNode *n);
    void makeEmpty(BinaryNode* &t);
    BinaryNode* clone(BinaryNode* t) const;
    BinaryNode* headNode;
    void printPostfixExpression(BinaryNode *n);
    size_t size(BinaryNode *t);
    size_t leaf_nodes(BinaryNode *t);
};
```

Next, here's the part of my .cpp file that's giving me errors. (they are the private functions):

```
/*----Public functions--(calls private functions)----*/

size_t BET::size(){
    size(headNode);
}

size_t BET::leaf_nodes(){
    leaf_nodes(headNode);
}

/*----Private functions--(returns num nodes)----*/

size_t BET::size(BinaryNode *t){
    if(t == NULL)
      return 0;
    else {
      int count = 1;
      count += BinaryNode(t->leftNode);    //line 218
      count += BinaryNode(t->rightNode);   //line 219
      return count;
    }
}

size_t BET::leaf_nodes(BinaryNode *t){
    int count = 0;
    if (t->leftNode == NULL && t->rightNode == NULL)
      count++;
    else {
      if (t->leftNode != NULL)
        count += BinaryNode(t->leftNode);    //line 230
      if (t->rightNode != NULL)
        count += BinaryNode(t->rightNode);   //line 232
    }
return count;
}
```

note: I know it's not suggested to have the interfaces in a separate file. But this is the way I have to do it.

Comment: why do you call the constructor instead of applying recursion at those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive call from within these functions but instead you are attempting to create a node and add the node to an integer. You need this sort of changes:

```
count += leaf_nodes(t->leftNode); //BinaryNode(t->leftNode);    //line 230
```

Answer (score 0):

You have either to dereference BinaryNode* pointer in your calls to BinaryNode constructor,

e.g.:

```
BinaryNode(*(t->leftNode));
```

or to provide BinaryNode constructor that would take `BinaryNode*` as an argument.

This is not all yet, because, as it was already mentioned, lines like `count += BinaryNode(t->leftNode);` aren't going to work, because you try to add an object instance to an integer, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That is only one of the problems. The fact that he does `count += BinaryNode(...)` isn't helping, and while your answer does fix the compiler errors he has now, it will just lead to new ones.